# Android Recompile Media library using NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk

I want to make a new video app. In this app, I have to modify the Http Live Streaming implementation of Android Media Player so that it could show an extra layer of information coming from the live stream.
I already located which files should I modify in order to add the change:
http://androidxref.com/4.0.4/xref/frameworks/base/media/libstagefright/httplive/LiveDataSource.cpp

However, I wonder even if I make the changes and recompile the libstagefright.so using NDK, then how should I make my changes effective my application? I mean if I have a new libstagefright.so and I call "System.loadLibrary("stagefright")", then would Android use my  recompiled version of libstagefright.so?

Or alternatively should I try to pull out every source files related to the android media player, then modify the namespaces, package names, etc. to make this my application-level libraries. This seems much work and I'm not sure whether this will work, can anyone advise? thanks.

Comment: Hey eroy4u, I'm trying to achieve the same thing you are for this. (Getting extra information from streaming Media) Did you ever get this working? If so, you have any advice? Cheers!

Comment: Sorry I didn't get that working. It requires too much work.